# Create workflow first time insert then update

Tags: etl, informatica-powercenter

I'm using Informatica PowerCenter 9.1.0 and to put it simple I have two identical tables as source (table A) and target (table B). The columns are ID and EMAIL.
I need to make a workflow where the very first time it runs all the records are copied from table A to B. 
Then every day I need to update in the target table B the rows modified in A (the mail can change). If in the source table the record is deleted I still want to see it in the target table.

I used these values 
Treat source rows as : "Insert"
Then in the Mapping tab I have checked the Attribute "Insert" and "Update as Update"

In the first time I have all the record in the target table but then if after few days some emails change I see no update. I still see the first email inserted the first time.

I changed the value of Treat source rows as to "Update" but in the first run (table B is empty ) it copies no row.

It's possible to have the workflow that in the first run insert all the rows the first time then in the next ones update the records without change the Treat source rows as value?

Comment: did you use update strategy? what kind of logic you are using to update the records, how do you identify which records got updated? do you have an updated timestamp in the table?

Answer (score 0):

Select the option "Update else insert" in the mapping tab. Keep "treat source rows as" as Update